# visual studio sql error

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Boas pessoal, eu sou novo em c# e então estou vendo uns tutoriais de ligação à base de dados só que aparece me este erro:

[image: erro]

O código que eu fiz é todo ainda com base num tutorial basico e deixo aqui para voces verem

```html
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace teste
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=teste; Integrated Security = true");
            {
                connection.Open();
                //
                // The SqlCommand should be created inside a using statement.
                // ... It receives the SQL statement as the first argument.
                // ... It receives the connection object as the second argument.
                // ... The SQL text only works with a specific database.
                //
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM my_cab",
                connection))
                {
                    //
                    // Instance methods can be used on the SqlCommand instance.
                    // ... These read data from executing the command.
                    //
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O que é que está mal?
Obrigado

Comment: Você instalou o SQL Server Express na sua máquina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez possa ser um erro em sua string de conexão

```
"Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=teste; Integrated Security = true"
```

Assegure-se que o SQL Server Express Edition esteja instalado e que o banco de dados **teste** exista em sua máquina local.

Comment: O problema era mesmo da string de conexao, vi na net outra maneira de a fazer e já deu.
Obrigado!

Comment: @Hugo Se essa resposta resolveu o problema considere marcá-la como a reposta certa. Isso ajuda outros usuários que passarem por algum problema semelhante a identificarem a solução.

Comment: Eu tinha marcado, nao sei que se passou, mas já marquei outra vez.
Obrigado pelo aviso ;)

Answer (score -1):

Uma pergunta: O nome da instância é essa que você passou? Tente passar o `Nome_da_Máquina\Nome_da_Instância`. Abra o `Sql Management` ou o `VS2013` e copie como está lá e cole aí no seu código(evita errar,rs). Se não resolver, verifique acessos e etc.

Fiz um método rápido aqui para simular um login de usuário e funciona. Faça os devidos arranjos e veja se funciona com você.

Meu método:

```
public bool login(string usu, string pwd)
        {
            bool retorno = false;

            string sql = "select idusuario,nm_usuario, tipo_usuario,senha_usuario from tbl_usuario where nm_usuario = '" + usu + "' and senha_usuario = '" + pwd + "'";

            SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection();
            conexao.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conectDarf"].ConnectionString;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            try
            {
                conexao.Open();
                cmd.Connection = conexao;

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    retorno = true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Erro = e.Message;
                retorno = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                conexao.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }

            return retorno;
        }
```

E assim está no `Web.config`, mas você pode passar para o seu `App.config`

```
<add name="conectDarf" connectionString="Server=COMPUTADOR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=INETGLOBAL;User ID=USUARIO;Password=SENHA"/>
```

Comment: O estranho é que se eu fizer um projeto do tipo windows form application ele funciona mas neste caso é um projeto do tipo Console e já não dá por isso nao deve ser o nome da instância porque se não daria mal nas duas acho eu

Comment: Hugo,ignore o downvote na resposta. Não há motivo para isso, mas tem uns caras aqui que se acham. Eu sei porque, é porque eu não coloquei nome da máquina e instância, mas esses ... deveriam saber que isso é uma forma genérica de responder, até porque eu não conheço sua máquina e etc..

Comment: Obrigado pnet mas já descobri a resposta! O erro estava na connection string, tentei fazer de outra maneira que vi na net e já deu